# Problemas con Footable de Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Resulta que debo validar unos checkbox dentro de una tabla que seria alterada por la funcion footable() de boostrap.
el problema es que ninguna funcion que aplique a algun campo dentro de esta tabla funciona.

```js
// $('#table').footable();
$('.check').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('ref');
  var i = 0;
  
  $('.check').each(function(valor, indice){
    if($(indice).attr('ref') != value)
    {
      $(indice).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if($(indice).is(':checked') == true)
    {
      i++;
    }
  });
  if(i == 0)
  {
    $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>check</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pepe</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pepe</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='2'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

La función de js que se ejecuta es la que uso para validar, pero si llego a ocupar otra 
Puden probar el codigo y ver que funciona dejando comentado el footable()
pero si se ejecuta, teniendo obviamente la libreria de esta, no pasa absolutamente nada.
Se puede encontrar la libreria de footable en [este link](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He revisado como funciona **Footable**, (aunque no pude realizar el ejemplo en el snippet ya que al incluir el `script` **CDN** de **Footable** sale un error de `script`). **Footable** remueve y añade los elementos al **DOM** a medida que navego entre las páginas por lo cual tu selector deberías de cambiarlo y hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on('change', '.check', function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('ref');
  var i = 0;

  $('.check').each(function(valor, indice){
    if($(indice).attr('ref') != value)
    {
      $(indice).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if($(indice).is(':checked') == true)
    {
      i++;
    }
  });
  if(i == 0)
  {
    $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Si tengo razón esto debería de funcionar correctamente y sin problemas.

Comment: Mañana a primera hora lo probare en el trabajo, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes  intentar agregarlo dentro de la función ready en jquery para que se ejecute una vez que se cargue el dom

ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.check').change(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr('ref');
      var i = 0;

      $('.check').each(function(valor, indice){
        if($(indice).attr('ref') != value)
        {
          $(indice).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if($(indice).is(':checked') == true)
        {
          i++;
        }
      });
      if(i == 0)
      {
        $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: El problema que tengo, es que no se ejecuta la funcion dek check si tengo la del footable activo y no entiendo el motivo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `DataTable();` y funciona correctamente tu código.

```js
$('#table').DataTable();
$('.check').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('ref');
  var valider = false;
  var i = 0;
  
  $('.check').each(function(valor, indice){
    if($(indice).attr('ref') != value)
    {
      $(indice).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if($(indice).is(':checked') == true)
    {
      i++;
    }
  });
  if(i == 0)
  {
    $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>check</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pepe</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pepe</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td><input type='checkbox' class='check' value='1' ref='2'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: El DataTable(); no es lo que busco, ya que la funcion footable(); altera y le da ciertos estilos a la tabla junto que funciones responsive y otros, por lo que debo usar esa funcion, el tema es que no logro entender el por que al usarla, no puedo usar otras funciones para tags que estan dentro de esta

Comment: Pues ya lo intente agregando las librerías de footable y tienes razón no funciona el código, me marca errores en el archivo `footable.js` y en el `footable.min.js` y no tengo la menor idea de que sea, espero alguien pueda orientarte acerca de esto, suerte.