# Problemas con diferentes funciones y Footable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Habia realizado una pregunta respecto a este tema y lograron solucionarla, pueden verla [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277885/problemas-con-footable-de-boostrap/277891?noredirect=1#comment511163_277891).

El tema es que ahora necesito realizar otra funcion mas, la cual al yo seleccionar un check, se seleccionen todos los otros check habilitados.

El problema que presento no es el desarrollo de la funcion, si no su ejecucion ya que al ocupar la funcion Footable(), no puedo ejecutar otras funciones de JQuery.

Logre ejecutar una funcion de la siguiente manera

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check', function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('ref');
  var i = 0;

  $('.check').each(function(valor, indice){
    if($(indice).attr('ref') != value)
    {
      $(indice).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    if($(indice).is(':checked') == true)
    {
      i++;
    }
  });
  if(i == 0)
  {
    $('.check').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Pero al intentar agregar una nueva funcion, no ejecuta nada.

Ya probe con el clasico

```js
$('#checkGeneral').click(function(){
  console.log('lo que necesite');
});
```

y tambien

```js
$(document).on('change', '.check', function(){
  console.log('Funcion anterior');
}).on('change'. '#checkGeneral', function(){
  console.log('lo que necesito ahora');
});
```

Y no hay forma de que esa segunda funcion se ejecute

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que no puedes atachar el mismo tipo de evento dos veces sobre el mismo elemento. Si tu nuevo `checkbox` ya tiene un evento `change` por tener la clase `.check`, no puedes añadirle uno nuevo por tener la id `#checkGeneral`.

Una solución sería que ese nuevo `checkbox` no tuviera la clase `.check` atachándole su propio evento `change` por su id.

Otra opción sería usar la misma función para todos los `checkbox`, como estás haciendo, e identificar dentro de la función a qué `checkbox` se le está haciendo el `change`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkGeneral" class="check" type="checkbox">
<input id="check2" class="check" type="checkbox">
<input id="check3" class="check" type="checkbox">
<input id="check4" class="check" type="checkbox">

<script>
  $(document).on('change', '.check', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'checkGeneral') {
      console.log('Lo que necesito ahora');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Función anterior');
    }
  });
</script>
```